# GCP cloud router not responding to ARP requests from BGP neighbor

Tags: arp, google-cloud-router

I am trying to create a BGP session between my router appliance and GCP cloud router (both are connected on the same subnet as usual). Once I configure the BGP neighborship on both end, I see the Cloud router’s connection TCP SYN request coming into my router appliance. But since my router appliance doesnt have ARP entry for the cloud router IP, it tries to resolve the mAC address through ARP request. But I dont see the response coming from Cloud router.

Is there any specific settings to be done in Cloud router configuration?

```
Packet trace: (192.168.100.10 is my router appliance and 100.2 and 100.3 are cloud router IPs)

05:18:02.062141 42:01:c0:a8:64:01 > 42:01:c0:a8:64:0a, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.100.2.42421 > 192.168.100.10.179: Flags [S], seq 2626298341, win 65535, options [mss 1350,sackOK,TS val 1980420628 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0

05:18:02.072313 42:01:c0:a8:64:01 > 42:01:c0:a8:64:0a, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.100.3.32877 > 192.168.100.10.179: Flags [S], seq 1024207481, win 65535, options [mss 1350,sackOK,TS val 2059405060 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0

05:18:02.209120 42:01:c0:a8:64:0a > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.100.3 tell 192.168.100.10, length 28

05:18:02.209120 42:01:c0:a8:64:0a > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.100.2 tell 192.168.100.10, length 28
```